# How to configure AWS ELB to block certain IP addresses? (known spammers)

Tags: amazon-web-services, spam, spam-prevention, amazon-elb

I am looking for a way to drop connections from known spam ip addresses on an Amazon's Elastic Load Balancer (ELB)?

I am currently doing this at the web server level (multiple instances, running behind the ELB), but wondering if there is a way to do it at the ELB. This way, I can avoid configuring each web server instance for this.

I typically pull the [Drop List](http://www.spamhaus.org/drop/drop.txt) from Spamhause.org every day and update my web server configuration

Comment: Update - See AWS WAF, specifically : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-import-ip-address-reputation-lists-to-automatically-update-aws-waf-ip-blacklists/

Answer (score 10):

I would try using VPC ACLs for that. First of all, ELBs inside VPC can use [Security Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/USVPC_ApplySG.html) but they only specify a traffic you **allow** in and out of an ELB. To actually **block** a traffic coming from a certain IP - an [ACL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html) would be the best.

For that to work - a pair of a public (internet-facing) and internal ELBs [need to be used](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/vpc-loadbalancer-types.html) with internal ELB protected by subnet ACL DENY rules.

Comment: Interesting. Could you elaborate or point me to literature which explains this in more detail? I have never used VPC earlier. Could this change make my setup more complex to manage?

Comment: [User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Introduction.html) would be a place to start. Yes, introducing VPC makes the setup more secure but more involved, as a result - there are more "moving parts" to manage: [ACLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html), [NAT](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html), [Internet Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html), and [Route Tables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Route_Tables.html).

Comment: In EC2-classic (a usual way to launch EC2 instances) instances are always launched in a public network. In VPC they're either launched in a public or a private network. Once in a private network - they can be totally isolated from the external world and only SSH-ed to from specific boxes in a public network (typically SSH gateway) or from inside organization (on-premises) network if VPC is connected to it which it doesn't have to.

Comment: You can associate a security group with an ELB, as long as it's in a VPC. Then just specify the security group rules as normal to block/allow traffic

Comment: ACL has a 40 rule maximum per list. Subnet can only use one lust. Makes it unfeasible for any true access control

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from an ELB that is not instantiated inside a VPC (at the date of this answer). If inside a VPC, check out the other answers. If not, you can switch to something more controlable, such as HAProxy or place CloudFlare (https://www.cloudflare.com/) in front of your ELB, which is probably a better option.

Comment: You can do this with ELB. ELBs in an IAM account can have a VPC associated with them, but still use normal security groups.

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconsistency in this case. Would it the be correct to specify that you can't do this with an ELB not associated with a VPC?

Comment: Yes I think that's the case

Comment: Thanks, Seb, I've edited my answer accordingly.