# How can I configure AWS ELB to block certain IP addresses, e.g., to block scrapers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip-blocking

In my web logs, I see a very large number of requests originating from the same IP address. A closer look at the type of requests leads to the conclusion that it is a scraper. How do I block the IP address of this scraper in AWS ELB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure AWS ELB to block certain IP addresses? (known spammers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123308/how-to-configure-aws-elb-to-block-certain-ip-addresses-known-spammers)

Answer (score 0):

Use the AWS console as follows:
1. Select AWS Service "VPC" 
[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGluc.png)

2. Select in the left menu "Network ACLs" 
3. Select the VPC in which your ELB is running, Click "Inbound Rules", Click "Edit", and supply rules to deny specific IP addresses. Give them a lower "Rule#" than the "Allow 0.0.0.0/0 rule, so that they are executed first.
[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upLGX.png)

Comment: I would use the WAF service for this instead of Network ACLs.